# ¿Cómo sumar un numero especifico de elementos en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendoui

Pues verán, tengo una lista con 10 preguntas en un json en los cuales tengo checkboxes, ya logré hacer la suma de los valores que le asigne a los checkboxes para todos los elementos

1. Como cambia la rubrica de suma, lo que no logro hacer (porque posiblemente estoy divagando mucho) es que solo se efectué la suma de la pregunta 1 al 5.
2. A partir de la pregunta 6 a la pregunta 10 hacer otra suma, cambiando los valores de los checkboxes

Estoy utilizando jquery, y kendui adjunto parte de mi codigo.

Aquí genero un json con los elementos que necesito

```
var JsonEscalaRos =
        [{Id: 1, Concepto: "Siento que soy una persona digna de aprecio, al menos en igual medida que los demás."}, 
         {Id: 2, Concepto: "Estoy convencido de que tengo cualidades buenas."}, 
         {Id: 3, Concepto: "Soy capaz de hacer las cosas tan bien como la mayoría de la gente."},
         {Id: 4, Concepto: "Tengo una actitud positiva hacia mi mismo/a."},
         {Id: 5, Concepto: "En general estoy satisfechola de mi mismola."},
         {Id: 6, Concepto: "Siento que no tengo mucho de lo que estar orgullosola."},
         {Id: 7, Concepto: "En general, me inclino a pensar que soy un fracasadola."},
         {Id: 8, Concepto: "Me gustaría poder sentir más respeto por mi mismo."},
         {Id: 9, Concepto: "Hay veces que realmente pienso que soy un inútil."},
         {Id: 10, Concepto: "A veces creo que no soy buena person"}];
```

Aca genero el grid y los templates (checkboxs) con kendo

```
$("#EscalaRosenbergGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: JsonEscalaRos,
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Id: {type: "number"},
                    Concepto: {type: "string"}   

                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10
    },

    scrollable: false,

    columns: [

        {field: "Concepto", title: "Concepto:", width: "50px"},
        {template: "<input type='checkbox' id=escalar#=Id#" + 1 + " class=escalar#=Id# onclick='CheckAHP(this,\"NoExisteP\",\"NoExisteP\", 43, \"escalar\", \"divEscalaRosenberg\", \"NoExisteP\", \"EscalaRosenbergGrid\", 3, \"Concepto\")' value='1'/>", title: "A", width: "50px"},
        {template: "<input type='checkbox' id=escalar#=Id#" + 2 + " class=escalar#=Id# onclick='CheckAHP(this,\"NoExisteP\",\"NoExisteP\", 43, \"escalar\", \"divEscalaRosenberg\", \"NoExisteP\", \"EscalaRosenbergGrid\", 3, \"Concepto\")' value='2' />", title: "B", width: "50px"},
        {template: "<input type='checkbox' id=escalar#=Id#" + 3 + " class=escalar#=Id# onclick='CheckAHP(this,\"NoExisteP\",\"NoExisteP\", 43, \"escalar\", \"divEscalaRosenberg\", \"NoExisteP\", \"EscalaRosenbergGrid\", 3, \"Concepto\")' value='3' />", title: "C", width: "50px"},
        {template: "<input type='checkbox' id=escalar#=Id#" + 4 + " class=escalar#=Id# onclick='CheckAHP(this,\"NoExisteP\",\"NoExisteP\", 43, \"escalar\", \"divEscalaRosenberg\", \"NoExisteP\", \"EscalaRosenbergGrid\", 3, \"Concepto\")' value='4' />", title: "D", width: "50px"}]
});
```

y por ultimo genero la suma de los valores de los checkbox hasta aquí me quede y ya no pude avanzar

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {

        total += parseInt($(this).val());

    });      
    $('#total').text(total);
    console.log(total);   
 });
```

Comment: Hola @JordanoTinoco intenta explicarte un poco mejor, porque no se entiende cual es el problema.

Comment: Lo siento, ya modifique, estoy divagando demasiado, entonces voy por partes, logré que se haga la suma de todos los checkboxes, pero en los requisitos me pide que se haga una suma del id 1 al 5 del json, después hacer otra suma del id 6 al 10 (esto porque a partir del id 6 cambian los valores de los checkboxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No queda claro la frase *"a partir del id 6 al 10 del json hacer otra suma"*. Esa oración esta bastante difusa porque no es nada objetiva con respecto a lo que quieres hacer, así que para darte una idea, lo que haré es separar las sumas de las preguntas del 1 al 5, y las preguntas del  5 al 10.

Lo primero que debes hacer, es agregar un atributo que identifique la pregunta. Para ello he agregado el atributo `pregunta` a tus templates:

```
columns: [
        { field: "Concepto", title: "Concepto:", width: "50px" },
        { template: "<input type='checkbox' pregunta=#=Id# ...} />" },
        { template: "<input type='checkbox' pregunta=#=Id# ...} />" },
        { template: "<input type='checkbox' pregunta=#=Id# ...} />" },
        { template: "<input type='checkbox' pregunta=#=Id# ...} />" }]
```

Luego cuando se dispara el evento on `click` selecciono el atributo pregunta para saber que pregunta fue seleccionada y a partir de ahí, hacer lo que necesites:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function (e) {
    var totalPrimerasCinco = 0;
    var totalSeisAlDiez = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function (e) {
        var pregunta = parseInt($(this).attr('pregunta'));
        var value = parseInt($(this).val());
        

        if(pregunta < 6){
            // Haces lo que necesites
            totalPrimerasCinco += value;
        }
        
        if(pregunta > 5){
            // Haces lo que necesites
            totalSeisAlDiez += value;
        }

    });
    $('#total').text(totalPrimerasCinco);
    console.log("Total del 1 al 5: " + totalPrimerasCinco);
    console.log("Total del 6 a 10: " + totalSeisAlDiez);
    
});
```

Te adjunto un ejemplo que puedes ejecutar desde acá. Nota que separé en dos variables la suma de las preguntas.

```js
var JsonEscalaRos =
    [{ Id: 1, Concepto: "Siento que soy una persona digna de aprecio, al menos en igual medida que los demás." },
    { Id: 2, Concepto: "Estoy convencido de que tengo cualidades buenas." },
    { Id: 3, Concepto: "Soy capaz de hacer las cosas tan bien como la mayoría de la gente." },
    { Id: 4, Concepto: "Tengo una actitud positiva hacia mi mismo/a." },
    { Id: 5, Concepto: "En general estoy satisfechola de mi mismola." },
    { Id: 6, Concepto: "Siento que no tengo mucho de lo que estar orgullosola." },
    { Id: 7, Concepto: "En general, me inclino a pensar que soy un fracasadola." },
    { Id: 8, Concepto: "Me gustaría poder sentir más respeto por mi mismo." },
    { Id: 9, Concepto: "Hay veces que realmente pienso que soy un inútil." },
    { Id: 10, Concepto: "A veces creo que no soy buena person" }];


$("#EscalaRosenbergGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: JsonEscalaRos,
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "number" },
                    Concepto: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10
    },

    scrollable: false,

    columns: [
        { field: "Concepto", title: "Concepto:", width: "50px" },
        { template: "<input type='checkbox' pregunta=#=Id# id=escalar#=Id#" + 1 + " class=escalar#=Id# value='1'/>", title: "A", width: "50px" },
        { template: "<input type='checkbox' pregunta=#=Id# id=escalar#=Id#" + 2 + " class=escalar#=Id# value='2' />", title: "B", width: "50px" },
        { template: "<input type='checkbox' pregunta=#=Id# id=escalar#=Id#" + 3 + " class=escalar#=Id# value='3' />", title: "C", width: "50px" },
        { template: "<input type='checkbox' pregunta=#=Id# id=escalar#=Id#" + 4 + " class=escalar#=Id# value='4' />", title: "D", width: "50px" }]
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function (e) {
    var totalPrimerasCinco = 0;
    var totalSeisAlDiez = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function (e) {
        var pregunta = parseInt($(this).attr('pregunta'));
        var value = parseInt($(this).val());
        

        if(pregunta < 6){
            // Haces lo que necesites
            totalPrimerasCinco += value;
        }
        
        if(pregunta > 5){
            // Haces lo que necesites
            totalSeisAlDiez += value;
        }

    });
    $('#total').text(totalPrimerasCinco + totalSeisAlDiez);
    console.log("Total del 1 al 5: " + totalPrimerasCinco);
    console.log("Total del 6 a 10: " + totalSeisAlDiez);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.412/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.412/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.412/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.412/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="EscalaRosenbergGrid"></div>
<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era precisamente lo que trataba de hacer, y perdón si no fui tan claro